# Drupal 8, Issues on theme a views block

Tags: views, theming

I´m not able to theme a views block. I have found a lot of tutorials on how to rename the twig file, but i´m sure that i´m doing anything wrong with filename.

I use the views-view.html.twig and i have copied it into my theme folder. The machine name of the views block is: views_block__kurstermine_block_1.

I have tried several block names, but no one works. Please can somebody explain me?

```
views-view--views_block__kurstermine_block_1.html.twig = false
views-view--views_block--kurstermine-block-1.html.twig = false
```

Thank you!

Comment: The solution is: block--views-block--kurstermine-block-1.html.twig

Comment: OR views-view--kustermine--block-1.html.twig

Comment: **views-view--[view-name]--[[machine-name](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg).tpl.php]**